# @RolesAllowed interfering with @RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

In a spring boot app, using annotations only, i want to implement security

I have added an `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr360Enabled=true)` to a configuration class. the class also has an `@EnableSecurity` anntation

Now, when i add a `@RolesAllowed` to any `@RestController` class, be it on method level or   level, the startup logs don't list the class at all. instead , there is line:
`'Rejected bean name (rest controller class): no URL paths identified'`.

Does anyone have an idea what might be causing this?

Comment: use `proxyTargetClass=true` on the `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity`.

Comment: it worked! Would you mind explaining why though? SO points await if you make a post that i can mark :D

Comment: @chaixdev https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.6.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/method/configuration/EnableGlobalMethodSecurity.html#proxyTargetClass--

Comment: @M.Deinum Could you verify my explanation below?

Comment: That looks like the explanation there is also some documentation on that in a reference guide. Not sure if it was Boot, Security of general Spring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After @M.Deinum set me on the path, i did some reading and have an explanation. If anyone can elaborate more or correct me on the more technical details, feel very welcome.

Spring proxies classes to wire beans together.

- Classes that *don't* implement an interface are proxied by using *CGLib* to make a subclass with additional functionality
- classes that *do* implement an interface, spring uses dynamic proxy to access the functionality of the class, but doing so it can *only* proxy interface methods.

in my case, my controller implements an interface with non-endpoint related methods, so spring ignored all handling methods and the RequestMappingHandlerMapping did not find any methods to bind, because if only 'saw' the interface methods on the class

using `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(proxyTargetClass=true)` forces the use of CGLib, so the full methods are recognised by our mapper.